# Is the order of setTimeout and non-timer (eg. UI) event callbacks guaranteed according to time?

Tags: javascript, events, asynchronous

Say we create a timer `setTimeout(f, 1000)` and and then a button with a click handler. If there is no synchronous code that runs after the setTimeout it is 'guaranteed' that a click handler, responding to a click within a second, will be invoked first.

However, consider when synchronous processing continues:

```
a_button.onclick = function () { console.log("ui") }
setTimeout(function () { console.log("timer") }, 1000)
s = Date.now()
while (Date.now() - s < 2000) { /* waste two seconds of CPU and block the UI */ }
```

Is there any guarantee which event will occur first when

- .. the button is pressed *before* one second has elapsed?
- .. the button is pressed *after* one second has elapsed?

That is, **are different kinds of events *ordered* according to when they 'occur'?**

If there is no guarantee, does the behavior change across browsers or is there a modus operandi?

If there is no guarantee for UI events, is any guarantee for Web Workers or XHR or image oncomplete events, etc?

Please provide resources covering, or disproving such a guarantee; or make a solid argument against, preferably with counter examples (in a way that can be tested without manually, and possibly incorrectly, clicking).

---

After reflecting on the article ["How JavaScript Timers Work"](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) in yvesmancera's comment, I suppose answering negated(?) aspects of the question would be sufficient:

- Is *every* pending UI event processed *before* expired timers? Before *other* kinds of pending events?
- Are events of (Web Works | XHR | internal DOM) processed before any expired timers? Does this behavior, with respect to timers, differ from UI event processing? How are these events ordered with respect to pending UI events?

Comment: John Resig, the author of jQuery explains how timeouts, intervals and asynchronous callbacks work in this blog post, I highly recommend it http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: @yvesmancera Thanks for the link, it is an interesting read. In particular I suppose I am asking about the ordering of events 'in queue' between callbacks - is it strictly a queue or is it a priority queue? And can it / does it vary by browser? The example above is a bit contrived (and possibly flawed, but with a repeatable outcome in Chrome) and leaves open the definition of 'when they occur'. Within timers alone the time-order is guaranteed: `setTimeout(first, 0); setTimeout(second, 0)` and (making a few minor assumptions) `setTimeout(second, 20); setTimeout(first, 10)`.

Comment: The specification states it's a list: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html Which means they will be executed in order of adding one after another.

Comment: @zerkms For timers it's pretty clear, and that actually led me to this question; is there a similar algorithm for how the *different* kinds of events  (could or could not) interleave? I should not have used "assumptions" in my previous comment as I picked the values with some care.

Comment: @user2864740 What do you mean by "interleave"?

Comment: @zerkms Imagine a block of code has executed (taking some amount of time), if during that time a timer elapsed and a Web Worker / XHR request (the original question uses a UI event, which was probably a poor choice) was received, is there a guarantee of which event (of different types) would invoke the callback first?

Comment: @user2864740 Yep, I see what you mean and updated the answer correspondingly.

Answer (score 1):

As [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html) states

> 8. Wait until any invocations of this algorithm started before this one whose `timeout` is equal to or less than this one's have completed.

Which means if the implementation is per the specification requirements, then:

1. `setTimeout(first, 0); setTimeout(second, 0)` --- for this code `first` will always fire before `second`
2. `setTimeout(second, 20); setTimeout(first, 10)` --- for this code `first` also will always fire before `second`

As of processing events from the different queues, that's what [another specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) states:

> 1. Run the **oldest** task on one of the event loop's task queues, ignoring tasks whose associated Documents are not fully active. The user agent may pick any task queue.

It honestly is not clear to me though, because of this "The user agent may pick any task queue." statement. I presume it allows an implementation to run them in an arbitrary order.